# tips to learn cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

can any body give me some tips to learn cherrypy? I have learn python, I only know the simple example code and successfully run it, But I could not build a real web application. The cherrypy documents is too hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same problem and after some research bought the book [CherryPy Essentials: Rapid Python Web Application](http://www.packtpub.com/CherryPy/book).

When I got the basic understanding down, I went on GitHub and looked for projects using CherryPy and looked through their code.

Comment: look for code on gitHub is good idea. "CherryPy Essentials",this book is too hard for me to learn, Especially the chapters except 1 and 2 chapter.

Comment: I understand, the project I've studied most because it uses a lot of the concepts is [CouchPotato](https://github.com/RuudBurger/CouchPotato).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not being specific as to what part of the documentation you are finding difficult, I can only suggest that you try something simpler, like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: There was a slight typo in your Flask link which I fixed - you were linking to the Pan Orthodox Christian Council of Greater Omaha!

Comment: @Chris - O.o I don't even know what to say to that! Thanks!